# Printing ASCII in C

Tags: c, for-loop, ascii

I'm trying to write a program that'll print out all ASCII characters using for loops, but it keeps going on infinite loop unless I take out 127, am I doing something wrong or is that how ASCII behaves?

This will crash (infinite loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

for (char i = -128; i <= 127; i++)
{
    printf("%d = %c\n", i, i);
}

return 0;
}
```

But this is fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

for (char i = -128; i < 127; i++)
{
    printf("%d = %c\n", i, i);
}

printf("%d = %c\n", 127, 127);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i <= 127` is always true if `i` is a signed 8-bit `char` type.

Comment: Loop from 0 not -127, there's no negative value ASCII char

Comment: Twos Complement springs to mind.

Comment: take a look at `CHAR_MAX` (from `limits.h`) and `char c = CHAR_MAX; c++;`.  Should give you a hint about your problem.

Comment: What compiler version are you using, and what warnings do you have enabled? Ideally there would be a compiler warning that `i <= 127` is always true, and you should investigate such warnings for possible bugs in your code.

Comment: Please note that "crash" is not the same as "infinite loop".  In the first case, your program terminates abnormally.  In the second case, your program continues to run happily for as long as you allow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the loop reaches `127`, it is allowed to continue.  Then, `127` is increased by 1.  Because this is `signed char`, it wraps to `-128`, which still meets the looping condition.  In fact, every value of `signed char` is less than or equal to `127`

The more normal thing to do is use a larger data type such as `int` for your loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    printf("%d = %c\n", i, i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a signed char can never be greater then `127`...

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("%d = %c\n", (char) 128, (char) 128);
    printf("%d = %c\n", (char) -128, (char) -128);
}
```

Outputs

```
-128 = �
-128 = �
```